# struts2 url to default namespace images

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, web-applications, struts2

I have a lot of images in some.address/webapp/images/ that are referenced in various JSPs across my application.

When the images are referenced in actions in the default namespace (/) they are retrieved fine with just: `<img src="images/x.png" />` but if the action is in another namespace obviously it tries to find the image at http://some.host/webapp/namespace/images/x.png

I need to be able to retrieve the proper path to the image in the JSP.

I tried this:

```
<img src="<s:url value='images/x.png' namespace='/' />" />
```

but the namespace appears to be ignored and it tries to access the image at the URL above.

What is the best way to resolve this without explicitly writing the full path in src attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<img src="<s:url value="/images/x.png"/>"/>
```

You would need a publicly accessible images folder.

ie: http://some.host/webapp/images/x.png would need to be a url that points at an image.

This is how my css files read:

```
<link href="<s:url value="/style/cssbase-min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

JavaScript looks like:

```
<script src="<s:url value="/script/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
```

Very useful to have css and js files defined like this, so if someone decides to deploy the application under a different name, which is perfectly reasonable your application will also be reasonable.